# could not build apk or run it on to a device

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic2

i was able to build and test apk on to my device by `cordova run android`,
now suddenly it got stuck could someone help me to fix this issue, i waited almost for 20 min but no changes.

This image has my ionic info and my build part

I reinstalled platform, updated android studio, npm cache clean. but nothing success full.

[image]

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: try ionic cordova run android

Comment: Actually i am trying to run apk on to my device but the process gets stuck in this line "subproject path ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the gradle, maybe it is being downloaded, which take forever..

You might wanna mannually download the gradle and specify the downloaded path in yout_app_directory/platforms/android/cordova/builders/GradleBuidler.js => maybe somewhere around line 202 var distributionUrl = 'your_gradle_path'

Answer (score 0):

Follows this 
cordova platform rm android 
Cordova platform add android

Open emulator or connect Device to the system then 
Cordova run android

This will help you .

Answer (score 0):

use command 'ionic cordova run android'

or

Update node version. The version you are using is 6.11.0 but ionic is 3.5.0. so please update node version and check again

or

If you are not using ionic3, then you can downgrade your ionic version using a command 'npm install -g ionic@2.2.0'. then use 'ionic run android'